# Permission Denied error when unzipping files

Tags: windows-7, winrar

I'm trying to unzip some files in a folder under `Program Files`. I keep getting a "permission denied" error with WinRAR on Windows 7 Professional.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You have to run WinRAR as an administrator, as it is trying to extract into a protected directory.